# Character all wrong in armature

Tags: animation, armature, workflow, pose-mode

I made this character for fun but I can't fix it in armature and when I put it in automatic weights and rotate a bone it looks all wrong. I've already tried to fix it in weight paint but without success. Please someone help me.

[image: By rotating the bone]
[image: Normal]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: @moonboots I have already put the Blend File for download

Answer (score 0):

Your faces are not correctly oriented (see image), recalculate with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> and parent again.

[image]

Comment: Oh my God Thanks!